# php str_replace and objects

Tags: php, string

Is it possible to change a sub-string of an object element
in the flow inside of a foreach loop? So what I try but it's not working.

```
$xml= '';

foreach ($objetcs as $object){

        str_replace('searched','replacement', $object->link);

        //then I would call a function to render my rss
        $xml .=$object->renderRSS();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace` will return a string or an array, it won't change original variable, so you should do `$object->link = str_replace('searched','replacement', $object->link);` if `$link` is `public`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$xml= '';

foreach ($objetcs as $object){

        $object->link = str_replace('searched','replacement', $object->link);

        //then I would call a function to render my rss
        $xml .=$object->renderRSS();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$object->link = str_replace('searched','replacement', $object->link);
```